# python post request using PIL Image

Tags: python, image, post, python-requests, python-imaging-library

`<PIL.WebPImagePlugin.WebPImageFile image mode=RGB size=1600x1600 at 0x1F4E779BA00>` this is the file type
when I do a post request I get this error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'WebPImageFile'` . How do I convert it to a bytes-like object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saving it into some file format. You can't just push abstract pixels over the wire :)

This example assumes the remote end can accept PNG files.

```
import io

image = ...  # However you get your image
bio = io.BinaryIO()  # `BinaryIO` is essentially a file in memory
image.save(bio, format="PNG")  # Since there is no filename,
                               # you need to be explicit about the format
bio.seek(0)  # rewind the file we wrote into
requests.post(..., files={'file': bio})
```

To send a filename to the API too, you'll need to specify the file as a tuple.

```
requests.post(..., files={'file': ('image.png', bio)})
```

Comment: i am getting a response `illegal file suffix`, it's comming from an api that I dont know the source code. How do I debug this?

Comment: I'd imagine it means the file must be named.  See my edit :)